# sapply() use on a vector that returns either a list or vector problem

Tags: function, sapply

i create this function in R, and I want to apply it to the vector ive also created why does it return a list and a vector of the results ?

````
```student_grade <- function(grade){
if (grade < 60) {
 print("F")} else { 
  if (grade < 70 & grade > 60 ){
   print("D")} else {
    if (grade < 80 & grade > 70){
      print("C")} else {
        if (grade < 90 & grade > 80){
          print("B")} else {
            print("A")}}}}}

grade <- c(99,100,34,56,77,88,67,56,67,78,66,78,90,12,44)
sapply(grade,student_grade)```
````

im getting this :

````
```[1] "A"
   [1] "A"
   [1] "F"
   [1] "F"
   [1] "C"
   [1] "B"
   [1] "D"
   [1] "F"
   [1] "D"
   [1] "C"
   [1] "D"
   [1] "C"
   [1] "A"
   [1] "F"
   [1] "F"
   [1] "A" "A" "F" "F" "C" "B" "D" "F" "D" "C" "D" "C" "A" "F" "F"```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to know how to get a vector instead of a list when using sapply in this case